# How can I pass parameters to a view using cradle (CouchDB)

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

Using [cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle), how am I able to pass parameters to a view in CouchDB?

**Update**

Say I want to return documents which match other properties than `_key` (the default)...

```
// document format
{
    _key,
    postHeading,
    postBody,
    postDate
}
```

What if I wanted to match documents against the `postHeading` property... How would I go about this? What would the view look like, and how would I pass a search string to that view?

At the moment I'm doing this...

```
database.get("980f2ba66d5c8f9c91b9204a4d00022a", function (error, document)
{           
});
```

I would like to access a view instead, and instead of the 40 character long auto-generated key, I'd like to pass a string, matching another property.

Something along the lines of this...

```
database.save("_design/posts", {
    single: {
        map: function (document)
        {
            if (document.postHeading == PARAMETER_PASSED_GOES_HERE)
                emit(null, document);
        }
    }
});

database.view("posts/single", function (error, documents)
{           
});
```

Comment: You mean when you are querying a view how would you pass for example descending=true in querystring?

Answer (score 3):

If you are querying a view try to pass second parameter as options object with your settings, for example:

```
db.view('characters/all', {descending: true}, function (err, res) {
    res.forEach(function (row) {
        sys.puts(row.name + " is on the " +
                 row.force + " side of the force.");
    });
});
```

Also be aware of this:

> Some query string parameters' values
>   have to be JSON-encoded.

---

**EDIT:**

As far as I know you can't create a view in CouchDB where you pass your custom parameter which will be used in map/reduce function code. You have to emit keys from your map function and based on them you can query the view with parameters like `startkey` and `endkey`. Try to look at [Database Queries the CouchDB Way](http://sitr.us/2009/06/30/database-queries-the-couchdb-way.html) article.

Comment: But the descending parameter is a standard CouchDB parameter. I'd like to pass a custom parameter. I've updated my question.

Answer (score -2):

```
db.get('vader', function (err, doc) {
    doc.name; // 'Darth Vader'
    assert.equal(doc.force, 'dark');
});
```

It looks like the searched value (parameter) here is 'dark' out of all force keys?

> Cradle is also able to fetch multiple
>   documents if you have a list of ids,
>   just pass an array to get:
>
> db.get(['luke', 'vader'], function
>   (err, doc) { ... });